# Service Fabric State configuration

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am designing a system that will have hundreds of millions of Stateful Actors, How do I control where the state is saved?

I want to configure the cluster to be composed of VMs that have attached storage to accommodate the high number of actor states that will be saved, and then configure the StateManager to use the attached disk of the VM.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify the ARM template that provisions your cluster nodes with an additional managed disk per instance:

```json
"dataDisks": [
    {
        "diskSizeGB": 128,
        "lun": 0,
        "createOption": "Empty",
        "caching": "ReadOnly",
        "managedDisk": {
            "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
        }
    }
]
```

2. Use PowerShell to initialize the disk:

```
Get-Disk |
    Where PartitionStyle -eq 'Raw' |
    Select-Object -First 1 |
    Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru |
    New-Partition -DriveLetter F -UseMaximumSize |
    Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "Data" -Confirm:$false
```

3. Update your cluster configuration to store state on a different location. (Keep in mind that this changes the state storage location of every service, not just your `ActorService`.):

```
"settings": {
    ...
    "nodeTypeRef": "[parameters('vmNodeType0Name')]",
    "dataPath": "F:\\\\SvcFab",
    "durabilityLevel": "Silver",
    ...
},
```

[This github repo](https://github.com/nmehlei/servicefabric-arm-template) seems to describe what you need.

4. To change the state manager for a single service, you need to make custom implementations of `IActorStateManager` and `IActorStateProvider` and pass them in the call to register your Actor type: `ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync`.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to fit the bill perfectly